# Find and show links after user input ver 2

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write native JS code that will find, show and count all links on a page for which a substring input matches. As far as I understand, the document.getElementsByTagName () method is needed here, but the general logic is still difficult for me to think out against the background of inexperience. Do I need to translate the link into a string? I will be glad for your help) The image shows how the script should work

[image]

```js
let count = 0;
function findURLs() {
    let input = document.querySelector('.input').value;
    let urls = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        if (urls[i].href.indexOf(input) !== -1) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;    
}
let text = document.getElementById("counter").textContent;
document.getElementById("counter").textContent = 'Found ' + count;
```

Answer (score 1):

iI's a better idea to select all links when the page loads. Otherwise, you will execute the same query each time you call findURLs function

```
let links = [...document.querySelector("a")];
function findURLs() {
    let input = document.querySelector('.input').value;
    return links.filter(x => x.href.includes(input)).length;
}
```